# How to tell if page is in view/edit mode in SPFx?

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling, spfx-extensions

Trying to build an extension to display differently based on if the page is in view or edit mode.

Is there a built in way to see if a modern Site Page is in Read or Edit display mode?

I know of `DisplayMode` in the `@microsoft/sp-core-library`, but that only seems to support whether or not an SPFx app is in `Read` or `Edit` mode.

Comment: Hi did you find any solution for this problem? Also can you tell us how to use `DisplayMode` in SPFx?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct answer is valid but it will not cover all the scenarios, if you need to detect the edit mode from an SPFx solution on a classic page the Mode=Edit will not be available.
A more reliable solution would be to use the **DisplayMode**

```
//Detect display mode on classic and modern pages pages
if(Environment.type == EnvironmentType.ClassicSharePoint){
let isInEditMode: boolean;
let interval: any;
interval = setInterval(function(){
  if (typeof (<any>window).SP.Ribbon !== 'undefined'){
    isInEditMode = (<any>window).SP.Ribbon.PageState.Handlers.isInEditMode();
    if(isInEditMode){
      //Classic SharePoint in Edit Mode
    }else{
      //Classic SharePoint in Read Mode
    }
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
},100) 
}else if(Environment.type == EnvironmentType.SharePoint){
if(this.displayMode == DisplayMode.Edit){
  //Modern SharePoint in Edit Mode
}else if(this.displayMode == DisplayMode.Read){
  //Modern SharePoint in Read Mode
}
}
```

More information about this can be fount [here](http://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2018/01/07/detect-sharepoint-environment-type-and-page-mode-from-an-spfx-web-part/)

Comment: Where are you getting `this.displayMode`'s value from?

Comment: Directly from the web part context. Forgot to mention that you should also to import the DisplayMode enumeration
     import { Environment, EnvironmentType, DisplayMode } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';

Comment: I'm still not seeing anything on the context.  https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/reference/spdx/sp-webpart-base/iwebpartcontext

Comment: It's here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/sp-webpart-base/baseclientsidewebpart

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I'll try play around with it again shortly.

Answer (score 3):

When the modern page is in edit mode. you can find there will be query string added on the url `Mode=Edit`. if you remove that query string the page will go in read mode. you can get query string values in the spfx webparts.

ex: `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/demosite1/SitePages/modernpage.aspx?Mode=Edit`

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I didn't think to check the simplest place to look.  Trying to over-complicate things I guess.