# Display SPFx Application Extension differently in Read/Edit mode of a Site Page

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling, spfx-extensions, react

#### Question:

Is there a utility built into SPFx or a React library to change what to render based on if the page is in read or edit mode?

Or more exactly, a way to switch the rendering when switching between read and edit mode.

> [How to tell if page is in view/edit mode in SPFx?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231846/how-to-tell-if-page-is-in-view-edit-mode-in-spfx)

#### Problem:

I am trying to display an edit version of an SPFx Extension when the Site page is in Edit mode.  I would like to display other information when the page is in Read mode.

I can get everything to render correctly on initial page load, but toggling between read/edit after that doesn't change anything.

#### Attempted Solutions:

The closest I've gotten is by using [History](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) and having my component re-render on URL change using:

```
history.listen(() => this.forceUpdate());
```

I tried this in conjunction with [react-url-query](https://github.com/pbeshai/react-url-query), but it doesn't seem that `history.listen()` is firing when going back-and-forth between read/edit modes even though the URL is updating.

#### Additional Notes:

I am NOT currently using either Redux or react-router.  I'm not sure if using those would help get me what I'm looking for or if this is more of a SharePoint issue.

The modern pages are built with React, is there a way I can use the same state to tell what mode the page is in?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of modern pages, you can override the webpart's `onDisplayModeChanged` method. However, according to the docs, as long as you do your display mode handling in the render method, it should just work.

From the source code (@v1.5.1):

```
/**
 * This event method is called when the display mode of a web part is changed.
 *
 * @remarks
 * The default implementation of this API calls
 * the web part render method to re-render the web part with the new display mode. If a web part developer does not
 * want a full re-render to happen on display mode change, they can override this API and perform specific updates
 * to the web part DOM to switch its display mode.
 *
 * @param oldDisplayMode - The old display mode.
 */
protected onDisplayModeChanged(oldDisplayMode: DisplayMode): void;
```